# Rails model scope to grab top 3 records ordered by a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a simple model association:

```
Product has_many Review
```

I iterated through the reviews for a product in my view, however, I only want to grab the top 3 reviews for a product, ordered by it's `score` integer field.

I would like to do something like:

```
@product = Product.find(1).includes(:testimonials, :stores, :top_three_reasons)
```

Then just iterate through:

```
@product.reviews.each do |x|
  puts x.title
end
```

---

How can I accomplish this? Currently for every product, we include every single review, and it's really slow. We'd just like to include the top three reviews, to avoid repeat queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a dedicated scope for `top_reviews`.

```
class Product << AR::Base
  has_many :top_reviews, -> {order(score: :desc).limit(3)}
end

...

@product = Product.find(1)
@product.top_reviews.each do |x|
  puts x.title
end
```

Comment: Right, but that means that for every `@product` I'll hit the database for every top review, correct? I'm trying to avoid that altogether.

Comment: Yeah, for every product you'll make a query to find the top three reviews. The best you could do is 2 queries. I don't know if AR can take a modified association in the `includes` to pull just the top three and easily or not :/

Answer (score 0):

What about like this,

```
@product.reviews.order("score DESC").limit(3).each do |x|
  puts x.title
end
```